# Is Azure Custom Translator based on general model?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm seriously considering training a NMT model using some domain data. Custom Translator seems a good option.

But I'm wondering whether the model offered by Azure is an empty model (never trained with language data) or is pretrained general model (like Bing Translator)?

If it's the former case, do I need to train the model with additional general domain data to achieve ideal results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom Translator enables customer to use their own domain specific dataset to build translation engine that speaks their domain terminology. Customizing with general domain data would not deliver the translation quality the customer desires.

If customer does not have a domain dataset, it would be better to use our general domain (or standard models like bing translate). For more info about Custom Translator, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-ai/customize-a-translation-to-make-sense-in-a-specific-context/ba-p/2811956